# Unkown node in applicationHost.config of IIS. Leaving website and app pool in unstable condition

Tags: iis

Please help us out in understanding what this node in the applicationHost.config mean:

Basically we need to know what are these property ids? I guess they are leaving the website in an unstable condition and most probably corrupting the bindings.

```
<customMetadata>
            <key path="LM/W3SVC">
                <property id="130001" dataType="String" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="BITS-Sessions" />
                <property id="130002" dataType="String" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="18446744073709551615" />
                <property id="130003" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="1209600" />
                <property id="130004" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="0" />
                <property id="130005" dataType="String" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="" />
                <property id="130007" dataType="String" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="" />
                <property id="130008" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="86400" />
                <property id="130010" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="0" />
                <property id="130011" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="1" />
                <property id="130012" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="12" />
                <property id="130013" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="1" />
                <property id="130014" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="0" />
                <property id="130015" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="0" />
                <property id="130016" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="0" />
                <property id="130017" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="50" />
                <property id="130018" dataType="DWord" userType="2" attributes="Inherit" value="0" />
                <property id="2073" dataType="MultiSZ" userType="1" attributes="Inherit" value="C:\windows\system32\bitssrv.dll&#xA;" />
            </key>
            <key path="LM/W3SVC/INFO">
                <property id="4012" dataType="String" userType="1" attributes="Inherit" value="NCSA Common Log File Format,Microsoft IIS Log File Format,W3C Extended Log File Format,ODBC Logging" />
                <property id="2120" dataType="MultiSZ" userType="1" attributes="None" value="400,0,,,0&#xA;" />
            </key>
        </customMetadata>
```

Comment: Please learn how to use Stack Overflow format. Otherwise, others won't be able to even see what you are talking about.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/custommetadata/ Regarding the tags you asked abuot, they are used to store legacy metadata, and in your case, very likely to be BITS related.